# BigInteger.isProbablePrime

Tags: java

I just want to confirm my intuition about this method. Consider the code below.

```
long knownPrime = // some large known prime
int certainty = // some integer greater than 0

BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(knownPrime);
boolean isPrime = b.isProbablePrime(certainty);
```

For a large known prime, and for any certainty > 0, is it accurate to say that `b.isProbablePrime(certainty)` will always return true?

Or are there any cases where the method "guesses" that a known prime number is composite?

Comment: Perhaps I completely misinterpreted the documentation the way I read it, if the value of certainty increases, then the accuracy of the answer should also increase? If that is correct, then yes, it should always return true, with a certainty of 1 would be the only point of potential error or "guessing." Of course I could have completely misunderstood that.

Comment: Actually, an answer to you question is contained in the method name. This method doesn't guess if number is composite, it guesses the opposite condition, i.e. method returns false (with any certainty) only if it's sure that number is composite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> For a large known prime, and for any certainty > 0, is it accurate to say that b.isProbablePrime(certainty) will always return true?

Yes. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime%28int%29) says it will return `false` only if it is certain that the number is composite.

> Returns:
>   true if this BigInteger is probably prime, false if it's **definitely** composite.

So the `certainty` parameter will influence only on the chance of a false-positive: saying a composite number is prime, when it really is not.

Answer (score 3):

For a large known prime `b`, and for any `certainty`, `b.isProbablePrime(certainty)` returns `true`.

`isProbablePrime` can only err by returning `true` when the input is not prime (an example is `b=6`, `certainty=0`, which returns `true`), never the other way (because the Rabin-Miller test, which `isProbablePrime` uses, can only fail in this direction).

Comment: I'd be interested to know where you found out that the method internally uses the Rabin-Miller test.

Comment: @Brandon Buck; see [this](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigInteger-source.html#1284)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime(int)), this method will return

> true if this BigInteger is probably prime, false if it's definitely composite.

So any definite (independently verified) prime number will, by definition, return true for any legal (>0) certainty/tolerance value is passed in.  The only thing the certainty/tolerance value changes is the occurrence of false-positives (true for composites) and the execution time of the method.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        long l = s.nextLong();
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(l));
        BigInteger p = b.nextProbablePrime();
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is always good, but it also helps to add some comments/context about how this code addresses the original question.