# how can i determine all prime numbers smaller than a given input value?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

Can anyone help me to determine all prime numbers smaller than a given input value using scanner with java8 .

> Input: N integer> 0
>
> Output: the table with prime numbers.
>
> Example: for N = 10 the Output is : 2 3 5 7

this is my work so far:

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N;
    int[] result = null;

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
        N = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
         
          for (int i = 0; i < (N/2)+1; i++) {
            if (N%i==0)
                result[i]=i;
        for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(result[j]);
            if (j < result.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You could use a [prime sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test, here you can choose you favorite method if you really want to make an algorithme. Bust honestly it think it would be easier for you to store an array with all primaries number under 10000 return a part of this array in you function.

Comment: why starting`i` with zero, why up to `N/2`?

Comment: @khelwood i can't write it with java !

Comment: @N8888 is not duplicated

Comment: @JulienMaret i need no much code the professor told me that is very simple :O

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger i was just thinkig that prime number less than a given number can't be > (given number )/2

Comment: @Mourag9 It was a duplicate.  You added the requirement for a scanner afterwards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Does your code already work as desired? If not, what is the difference? What are you still missing? I am sorry, but as your question stands it is too unclear.

Comment: You do not provide a fundamental information: what is the largest N that you target ? Depending on this, the implementations can be quite different.

Comment: the larget N is 500

Comment: @OleV.V. you are correct, that was for divisor of a number, not prime less than a number. but my original comment / *question* is still valid why start with zero and why up to N/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code problem is `int i = 0` start with `0` and next line `if (N%i==0)` so `10/0` is not possible throw a error something like `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` is not possible

and you loop through `result.length`, you need to loop through `i` your parent loop and put condition inside `if (N%i==0)` and you need many changes saw my below answer and debug where you get unexpected output and follow.

brute Force

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 50;
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i - 1; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                result.add(i);
            }
        }
        result.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
```

optimize one using `Math.sqrt` [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347468/return-all-prime-numbers-smaller-than-m)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 101;
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(i - 1); j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                result.add(i);
            }
        }
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

using `BigInteger.isProbablePrime` [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155191/biginteger-isprobableprime)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 101;
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (long i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            BigInteger integer = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
            if (integer.isProbablePrime(1)) {
                result.add((int) i);
            }
        }
        result.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
```

**Updated 1**:- that something you want

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
            int N = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            int[] result = new int[N];
            int resultIncreamenter = 0;
            // here for loop logic can be replaced with above 3 logic
            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
                boolean isPrime = true;
                for (int j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(i - 1); j++) {
                    if (i % j == 0) {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime) {
                    result[resultIncreamenter++] = i;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(result[j]);
                if (j < result.length - 1) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
```

Comment: thanks :) but i always have a problem with the input with scanner ..! if you look for the 1st code i must change here 
/* for (int i = 0; i < (N/2)+1; i++) { if (N%i==0) result[i]=i; */ 
not in other places that what the professor say

Comment: @Mourad9 updated answer with that you want

Comment: thanks 
would you give me you email plz i have something to ask for

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm using the Sieve of Eratosthenes taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347468/return-all-prime-numbers-smaller-than-m):

```
private static int findNumberOfPrimes(int length) {
    int numberOfPrimes = 1;
    if (length == 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    int[] arr = new int[length];
    //creating an array of numbers less than 'length'
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    //starting with first prime number 2, all the numbers divisible by 2(and upcoming) is replaced with -1
    for (int i = 2; i < arr.length && arr[i] != -1; i++) {

        for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] % arr[i] == 0) {
                arr[j] = -1;
                numberOfPrimes += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberOfPrimes;
}
```

**Update** :

and this is how you list them :

```
package primelessthanN;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j;
        int n;
        n = 10;

        for (j = 2; j <=n; j++) {
            if (isPrime(j))
                System.out.println(j);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int m) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(m); i++) {
            if (m % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: here you count the number of primes not the primes themselves !

Comment: You didn't say you wanted the primes themselves.  But I updated it to include that as well. You can make n equal to whatever.  Here it is for the value of 10

Comment: i always have a problem with the input with scanner ..! if you look for the 1st code i must change here /* 
  for (int i = 0; i < (N/2)+1; i++) {
            if (N%i==0)
                result[i]=i;  
*/ 
not in other places that what the professor say

Answer (score 0):

You lost the overview, though you have all functionality within reach.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (n/2)+1; i++) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        boolean printed = false;
        for (int j = 2; j < N; j++) {
            if (isPrime(j)) {
                if (printed) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(j);
                printed = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Simply use abstractions like `isPrime`.

Now for improvements (your `results` array): use the already found primes instead of all numbers in testing:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n, int[] priorPrimes, int primesCount) {
    for (int p : priorPrimes) {
        if (n%p == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        int[] primes = new int[N];
        int primesCount = 0;
        boolean printed = false;
        for (int j = 2; j < N; j++) {
            if (isPrime(j)) {
                primes[primesCount] = j;
                ++primesCount;
                if (printed) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print(j);
                printed = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```