# What would cause java.io.FIleNotFoundException (access is denied)?

Tags: java, extentreports

I am trying to save an extent report to my documents folder. I am getting an access is denied problem.

I have tried giving java full control, through all the user groups. I have given jetbrains full control as well but still access is denied.

This is where I am trying to save the file.

```
    public void beforeSuite() {
        extent = ExtentManager.createInstance("MobileCustomerCare_" + fileName + ".html");
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "//Documents/ExtentReport//");

        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
```

I have added the ExtentManager class where the instance gets created

```
public class ExtentManager {

    private static ExtentReports extent;
    private static String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm").format(new Date());


    static ExtentReports createInstance(String fileName) {
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(fileName);
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
        htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle(fileName);
        htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName(fileName);

        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

        return extent;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have now changed to use `ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "//Documents/ExtentReport//");` But still getting (access is denied)

I am expecting it to save the file in the location specified. What it's actually doing is saving it in my project.

Comment: Could you show us exactly how your code that saves the file looks? Should be some lines in the `ExtendHtmlReporter`...

Comment: I have added the ExtentManager class.

Comment: Try an other path, maybe it must be a file path, not a directory or vice versa.

Comment: Change the line to ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\Documents\ExtentReport\");

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no path separator between the folder name and the file name, please try adding a path separator while creating ExtentHtmlReporter Object

```
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("C:\\Users\\tom.cockram\\Documents\\ExtentReport\\");
```

Try not to keep spaces in the file name, it will help you in future

```
public static ExtentReports getInstance() {
    if (extent == null)
        createInstance("MobileCustomerCare_" + fileName + ".html");

        return extent;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same problem with adding _ to the end of my file names

Comment: did you add `C:\\Users\\tom.cockram\\Documents\\ExtentReport\\\` as well ? I think the main problem is there

Comment: I did also add that unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

i had this problem when i was generating an XML file 
try this :
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("C://Users//tom.cockram//Documents//ExtentReport");

Comment: But with a single /

Comment: Try it *why*? You have to explain. Mere guesswork is not sufficient.

Comment: @JoopEggen i have some problem with java can you see that with me plz
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353945/how-can-i-determine-all-prime-numbers-smaller-than-a-given-input-value/55354568?noredirect=1#comment97433437_55354568

Comment: @JoopEggen would you give me your email plz !